# Unable to use make to install Valgrind

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I am attempting to download and install Valgrind using the following instructions:

[image: Instructions]

I get through step 3 just fine, but when I type

```
make
```

I get the message

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

When I look through the new Valgrind directory I see files such as "Makefile.am" and "Makefile.in," but as indicated no "Makefile." The README file contains the same instructions as I posted in the picture, so I do not quite understand what I am missing. Thanks for any help!

Comment: What distribution are you using? Does your distribution not have a Valgrind binary package?

Comment: @dleggas: would be preferable if you pasted the text instead of a screenshot with that text. Advantage of actual text: search engines index it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The step `./configure` normally reads `Makefile.in` and writes `Makefile`. Something went wrong in running it. Run it again and read the output looking for errors. If that fails, read `config.log` where you might find a clue about what went wrong.

Comment: I see this "configure: error: Valgrind works on Darwin 10.x, 11.x, 12.x and 13.x (Mac OS X 10.6/7/8/9)" I am using 10.10, so I am assuming this is the issue?

Comment: @dleggas Aha! Then this question is uncovered as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26564125/yosemite-and-valgrind

Comment: Yes thank you! I discovered this after posting this comment...Thanks for the information anyhow, I did not know this.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that step 3 (Configuring) has failed. Didn't you got any error at step 3? (For the third step you need glibc also installed, make sure you have this).

Furthermore, why don't you use the package management? Like apt-get install valgrind?

Which distro are u using?

Answer (score 1):

This is the reason why it fails on my build:

checking for the kernel version... unsupported (3.14.13-c9)
configure: error: Valgrind works on kernels 2.4, 2.6